# How to load data from JSON in Jekyll

Tags: json, jekyll

While exploring Jekyll for site generation I faced with a JSON data loading problem. I've generated default Jekyll site, added `tracks.json` file to `_data` folder and added this code to default `index.html`

```
<span>Tracks:</span>
<ul>
  {% for track in site.data.tracks.tracks %}
    <li>Title: {{ track.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

In a result I've got this code generated:

```
<span>Tracks:</span>
<ul>
</ul>
```

`tracks.json` looks like:

```
{
   "tracks":[
      {
         "id":"140",
         "title":"Android"
      },
      {
         "id":"142",
         "title":"GDG[x]"
      }
   ]
}
```

Am I using the right way to access JSON fields? If not, what is the right way?

**UPDATE:**  issue was fixed in [Jekyll v.2.1.0](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#v2-1-0)

Answer (score 6):

You can make your top-level element in the .json file an array like this:

```
[{
  "id":"140",
  "title":"Android"
},
{
  "id":"142",
  "title":"GDG[x]"
}]
```

Then you can access it more simply like this `{% for track in site.data.tracks %}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try it by `site.data.tracks[0].tracks`. Have a good time. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Ourai, since [v.2.10](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#v2-1-0) this issue is fixed

Comment: That [0] is unnecessary these days

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to put your data in `track.json` like this:

```
{
   "atribut": "Jekyll site generation with JSON data",
   "gallery":[
      {
     "group":"Tracks",
     "items":[
            {
               "id":"140",
               "title":"Android"
            },
            {
               "id":"142",
               "title":"GDG[x]"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You may put [other attributes](https://github.com/chetabahana/chetabahana.github.io/blob/master/_data/portfolio.json) as many as you like and access the data like this:

```
{% for product in site.data.track.gallery %}
<span>{{ product.group }}:</span>
<ul>
    {% for item in product.items %}
    <li>Title: {{ item.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The output will remain be the same as expected:

```
<span>Tracks:</span>
<ul>
    <li>Title: Android</li>
    <li>Title: GDG[x]</li>
</ul>
```

The benefit is that you are free to justify that JSON file at any time without disturbing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend to use yaml instead :) . It's natively supported by Jekyll (you can put it in _config.yml (then you can use it in many pages) or in page's YAML Front matter (then it's available to the page itself). When you put it there, the data is parsed by jekyll and you can use it directly from there.

You can even convert your Json to Yaml fairly easily:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/json2yaml

And Yaml is quite nice format, in some ways even better than JSON

Comment: I'd like to, but we already have backend that generates JSON files for Android app, and I don't want to introduce one more format

Comment: That was for old version of Jekyll. The versions released afterwards supported .json natively so the answer is not valid any more.